# Conservation of momentum involved in explosions

Tags: forces, momentum, conservation-laws, vectors, explosions

Bomb explosion is an example for conservation of momentum.Initial momentum of the bomb or the system is said to be equal to final momentum of the system.How is this possible?The individual particles are in motion after the explosion,right?Then how is final momentum and initial momentum the same.I can't visualise.Help me visualise. ;)

If for example for easy method of understanding,a bomb consisted of three identical particles.Initial momentum is zero.But how can final momentum be zero.Arent the three particles move in the x,y,z plane with different velocities in different directions?

Comment: Think of vectors and how they add (and subtract.....)

Comment: Please read our [FAQ on writing good question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your system is two masses one at each on of a massless spring on a horizontal frictionless surface.
The spring is compressed by moving the two masses together and then the masses are released.
The two masses fly apart and detach themselves from the spring.
The initial momentum of the two masses before release was zero and so will be the final momentum of the two masses after release.
This is because there are no external horizontal forces acting on the system
In this case the centre of mass of the two masses does not move.

Now add a few more masses and replace the spring with a chemical reaction which produces expanding gases and you have a similar situation to having two masses and a spring.
The system is all the masses and the chemicals which finished up as an expanding gas.
All the forces between the expanding gas and the masses are internal forces and so they cannot change the momentum of the system.